# overflow set to scroll but still not able to scroll the web page

Tags: html, css

I have set the overflow to scroll but still i am unable to scroll my web page.
the overflow is reset to hidden automatically once i build and view my web page in visual studio. i also tried adding height in my css but did not work.

[image]

Below is my CSS Code :

```
body
     {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
        overflow: scroll;
        background-color: #ececec;
        color: #102c58;
    }
```

Comment: `height` property is missing in css

Answer (score 0):

If you add height in your CSS then your scroll will work, without `height` scroll is not working.

Try: `height:500px;`

Comment: @NisargKotak add `!important`

Comment: @NisargKotak Go to line 28 in your CSS and remove `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Did that too.Still doesn't work. Every time I build the web page it sets overflow back to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Height is missing in CSS. Add `height` in CSS

```css
div.ex1 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 110px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
   
<div class="ex1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
```